# Get complete json body from csv in Jmeter

Tags: json, csv, jmeter

I have a CSV file like this

> "{""data"":{""student"":{""name"":""random name""}}}",
> "{""data"":{""student"":{""name"":""random name2""}}}"

CSV image for better understanding:
[image]

Here I have two JSON strings.

I tried to send these as a JMeter variable as a POST `${body}`. It actually takes the value from the CSV, but JMeter sends the value as a string rather than a JSON body. Is there any way to perse those data from CSV and send those as a POST JSON body?

For example, the POST body should be like this:

```
{
"data": {
    "student": {
        "name": "random name"
    }
}
```

}

But now, it's like this

```
"{""data"":{""student"":{""name"":""random name""}}}"
```

I config the CSV data set in JMeter and send the variable this way:
[image]

Just for your info, I do not want to separate the data from the JSON one by one and put variables in the POST body for every JSON data separately. I want the full JSON body from the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter sends what it finds in CSV file, remove extra quotation marks from the CSV file and JMeter will start sending the valid JSON.

If you cannot manipulate the data in the CSV file, i.e. it's coming from an external source, you can remove these extra quotation marks using [JSR223 PreProcessor.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

If you want just to send new line from the file with each subsequent request and the file is not very big take a look at [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile), it just returns the next line from the file each time it's being called.

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Comment: 1. Thanks, @Dmitri. I can modify the file. But if I remove the extra quotations, the CSV becomes invalid.
2. My CSV file is actually more complex than the example I shared. It has some commas inside the JSON strings. Now, when JMeter sends data to my application, it breaks the single csv data with that comma. I think. it's a JMeter bug. 
3. My file is way too big. Creating txt file for every request will not fit my situation. 
Thanks for you reply btw.